# Cakephp 3 plugin Event

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have created a plugin called WdContactForm in cakephp3.
Inside a function of the plugin controller I need to send an email
But returns me this error:

```
Could not send email: Declaration of WdContactForm\Controller\AppController::beforeFilter() should be compatible with App\Controller\AppController::beforeFilter()
```

I have already read about adding:

```
use Cake\Event\Event;
```

I have already done it.
But I can't fix the problem

This is my controller inside plugin:

```
namespace WdContactForm\Controller;

use Cake\Event\Event;
use WdContactForm\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Core\App;
use Cake\Utility\Security;
use Cake\Utility\Inflector;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Mailer\Email;

class ContactFormsController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Admin');
    }
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        //other functions
        //...
    }

    public function send_email()
    {
        $email = new Email('default');

        $email->from(['test@test.it' => 'My Site'])
            ->to('test@test.it')
            ->subject('About')
            ->send('My message');
   }
}
```

And this is my AppController inside the plugin:

```
namespace WdContactForm\Controller;

use Cake\Event\Event;
use App\Controller\AppController as BaseController;


class AppController extends BaseController
{
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: That looks like it should work. Have you tried directly specifying the namespace on the `beforeFilter` param like this: `public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\Event $event)`?

Comment: What does your App\Controller\AppController look like. The error says it does not match the beforeFilter method of this appController.

Comment: From the looks of it you either have a problem with your beforeFilter() on your main AppController or it's missing